# Should I use plastic/insulating washers when attaching a motherboard to the case?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

I'm screwing in a motherboard, around the screw holes in the motherboard there is a white painted circle and inside that circle are what look like eight pieces of solder.

Do I need to put plastic/paper washers between the screws and the motherboard? Each screw goes into a little metal stand which is clipped onto the metallic case. If I don't use plastic washers will there be an issue with static?

Comment: I've suspect screw kits include these just to up the part count.  Tossing in 50 of these costs almost nothing in both money and weight.

Answer (score 12):

**NO**, you should not include a washer.  Those screws are supposed to make electrical contact with the metal on the motherboard, grounding the motherboard to the case.  The multiple grounds improve stability of the system (prevents voltage gradients), and reduces the chance of a spark happening between the motherboard & case, or motherboard & PSU, should any static buildup occur.

If you do happen to use a washer, make sure it is the proper size, and is **conductive** (e.g. non-insulating).  If the motherboard was not electrically connected to the case, there exists the chance for a voltage drop to occur between the case and motherboard, so now you have a giant capacitor (two charged plates separated between a dielectric).

---

**TL,DR**:  Don't use insulated washers to prevent static discharge from happening (or use conductive ones).

Comment: TL:DR: for 2 paragraphs? How busy are people these days they can't read that? :) +1

Answer (score 3):

If you had to use those, they would come with the motherboard (or the case, I'm not entirely sure). It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use non-conductive washers, for the reason you hinted and also possibly for the circuit to be grounded.